# php html login page execution

Tags: php, html, authentication, facebook-login

can anyone please check error in my page. I am new to HTML+ php & wantto execute page but unable to do so. Here is my designed page {php} which I expected to run -`

```
<div class="limiter">
   <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="container-login100" style="background-image: url('images/bg-01.jpg');">
        <div class="wrap-login100 p-l-110 p-r-110 p-t-62 p-b-33">
            <form class="login100-form validate-form flex-sb flex-w">
                <span class="login100-form-title p-b-53">
                    <p>Sign In With</p>
                </span>
                <?php 
                if(!empty($login_err)){
                    echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">' . $login_err . '</div>';
                }        
                ?>

                <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="post">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        
                        <a href="#" class="btn-face m-b-20">
                            <i class="fa fa-facebook-official"></i>
                            Facebook
                        </a>

                        <a href="#" class="btn-google m-b-20">
                            <img src="images/icons/icon-google.png" alt="GOOGLE">
                            Google
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="p-t-31 p-b-9">
                            <span class="txt1">
                                <label>Email</label>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate = "Username is required">
                            <input class="input100" type="text" name="email" class="form-control <?php echo (!empty($username_err)) ? 'is-invalid' : ''; ?>" value="<?php echo $email; ?>"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="p-t-13 p-b-9">
                            <span class="txt1">
                                <label>Password</label>
                            </span>

                            <a href="#" class="txt2 bo1 m-l-5">
                                Forgot?
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate = "Password is required">
                            <input class="input100" type="password" name="password" class="form-control <?php echo (!empty($password_err)) ? 'is-invalid' : ''; ?>">
            <span class="invalid-feedback"><?php echo $password_err; ?></span>
                            <span class="focus-input100"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="container-login100-form-btn m-t-17">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <button class="login100-form-btn">
                            Sign In
                        </button>
                        <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btm btn-primary" value="submit">
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Login">
                    </div>

                        <div class="w-full text-center p-t-55">
                            <span class="txt2">
                                Not a member?
                            </span>

                            <a href="register.php" class="txt2 bo1">
                                Sign up now
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<div id="dropDownSelect1"></div>

<script src=" -----"</script>
```

`
but it's not working.
here's my html-`
    
    
        
            
                
                    
                        Sign In With

```
                <a href="#" class="btn-face m-b-20">
                    <i class="fa fa-facebook-official"></i>
                    Facebook
                </a>

                <a href="#" class="btn-google m-b-20">
                    <img src="images/icons/icon-google.png" alt="GOOGLE">
                    Google
                </a>
                
                <div class="p-t-31 p-b-9">
                    <span class="txt1">
                        Username
                    </span>
                </div>
                <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate = "Username is required">
                    <input class="input100" type="text" name="username" >
                    <span class="focus-input100"></span>
                </div>
                
                <div class="p-t-13 p-b-9">
                    <span class="txt1">
                        Password
                    </span>

                    <a href="#" class="txt2 bo1 m-l-5">
                        Forgot?
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate = "Password is required">
                    <input class="input100" type="password" name="pass" >
                    <span class="focus-input100"></span>
                </div>

                <div class="container-login100-form-btn m-t-17">
                    <button class="login100-form-btn">
                        Sign In
                    </button>
                </div>

                <div class="w-full text-center p-t-55">
                    <span class="txt2">
                        Not a member?
                    </span>

                    <a href="#" class="txt2 bo1">
                        Sign up now
                    </a>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<div id="dropDownSelect1"></div>
```

can someone please help to execute it { rest everything is working fine in simple php page }`

Comment: What is the meaning of not working? Please include any error messages, the output you are receiving now and the expected output

Comment: Did you use a server in order to run the page? it works in mine

Comment: yeah , I used MySQL {of domain host}...Simple php program worked very fine...I mean records got added ot SQL but as I turned tothe above HTML integration it didn't work...I mean nothing was executed. I'm new to this so I don't know How To...can you please point out error and provide correct one.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey here's the correct one-

`

```
<div class="limiter">
    <div class="container-login100" style="background-image: url('images/bg-01.jpg');">
        <div class="wrap-login100 p-l-110 p-r-110 p-t-62 p-b-33">
            <?php 
            if(!empty($login_err)){
                echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">' . $login_err . '</div>';
            }        
            ?>
            <form class="login100-form validate-form flex-sb flex-w" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="post">
                <span class="login100-form-title p-b-53">
                    Sign In With
                </span>

                <a href="#" class="btn-face m-b-20">
                    <i class="fa fa-facebook-official"></i>
                    Facebook
                </a>

                <a href="#" class="btn-google m-b-20">
                    <img src="images/icons/icon-google.png" alt="GOOGLE">
                    Google
                </a>
                
                <div class="p-t-31 p-b-9">
                    <span class="txt1">
                        Username
                    </span>
                </div>
                <div class="wrap-input100 user">
                    <input class="input100" type="text" name="username" >
                    <span class="focus-input100"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="p-t-31 p-b-9">
                    <span class="txt1">
                        Email
                    </span>
                </div>
                <div class="wrap-input100 mail" >
                    <input class="input100" type="email" name="email" >
                    <span class="focus-input100"></span>
                </div>
                            
                <div class="p-t-13 p-b-9">
                    <span class="txt1">
                        Password
                    </span>

                    <a href="#" class="txt2 bo1 m-l-5">
                        Forgot?
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate = "Password is required">
                    <input class="input100" type="password" name="password" >
                    <span class="focus-input100"></span>
                </div>

                <div class="container-login100-form-btn m-t-17">
                    <button class="login100-form-btn">
                        Sign In
                    </button>
                </div>

                <div class="w-full text-center p-t-55">
                    <span class="txt2">
                        Not a member?
                    </span>

                    <a href="#" class="txt2 bo1">
                        Sign up now
                    </a>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>`
```